# Add a synonym for tag [rnc]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I have added the tag [rnc](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rnc). Would a Mod be so kind as to add the tag [republican-national-committee](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/republican-national-committee) as a synonym. This would be similar to the combination of [dnc](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnc) with [democratic-national-committee](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/democratic-national-committee) as a synonym.